# Filter a many-to-many relation using a list of values

Tags: knex.js, objection.js

I'm using objection.js and knex.js for my RESTful API.

In my database, I have three tables: `products`, `characteristics` and `product_characteristics` (join table with extra column named 'value').

So what I'm trying to do is to fetch all the products that have the corresponding characteristic values.

At the GET request, I accept a `characteristics` query parameter and parse it to get the array of characteristics by which I need to filter my products.

parsed characteristics Array:

```
[{
   characteristicId: number,
   value: string
}, ...]
```

'products' table fields:

```
[id, title, price, discount]
```

'characteristic's table fields:

```
[id, name]
```

'product_characteristics' join table fields:

```
[productId, characteristicId, value]
```

Currently I fetch all the products using objection's `queryBuilder` and `withGraphFetch` method, and the `page` and `limit` methods:

```
const query: any = ProductModel.query()
  .page(page - 1, limit)
  .orderBy(sortBy, order)
  .withGraphFetched({
    category: true,
    images: true,
    characteristics: true,
  });

const result = await query;
return {
  products: result.results,
  total: result.total,
};
```

Objection.js provides the `withGraphJoined` method, which gives access to the related entities inside the `queryBuilder` so that it can be used to filter the `parentModel` based on the relations, but it does not support the `page` and `limit` methods.

So one of the possible solutions is to execute raw SQL query using the `knex.raw()` method. But I have spent a day trying to write raw SQL query to fetch all the needed data.

The desirable outcome is a characteristics-filtered products array with all product related characteristics as the JSON response parameter.

```
const products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Pipe 1',
    price: 3000,
    discount: 500,
    characteristics: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'diameter',
        value: '120 mm',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'color',
        value: 'black',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Pipe 2',
    price: 5000,
    discount: 0,
    characteristics: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'diameter',
        value: '120 mm',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'color',
        value: 'blue',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the SQL query you're trying to write is

```sql
SELECT
  p.id,
  p.title,
  p.price,
  p.discount,
  c.name characteristicName,
  pc.value characteristicValue
FROM
  products p
  INNER JOIN product_characteristics pc ON pc.productId = p.id
  INNER JOIN characteristics c ON c.id = pc.characteristicId
WHERE
  (c.id = 1 AND pc.value = 'value1')
  OR (c.id = 2 AND pc.value = 'value2')
  OR (c.id = 3 AND pc.value = 'value3')
```

which can be achieved in knex like this

```js
knex({p: 'products'})
  .join({pc: 'product_characteristics'}, 'pc.productId', '=', 'p.id')
  .join({c: 'characteristics'}, 'c.id', '=', 'pc.characteristicId')
  .where(builder =>
    characteristics.forEach(item =>
      builder.orWhere(builder =>
        builder
          .andWhere('c.id', '=', item.characteristicId)
          .andWhere('pc.value', '=', item.value)
      )
    )
  )
  .select('p.id', 'p.title', 'p.price' /* etc */)
```

You can easily add [`.offset()`](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-offset) and [`.limit()`](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-limit) to this in order to support paging. It will translate to this SQL:

```sql
select
  "p"."id",
  "p"."title",
  "p"."price"
from
  "products" as "p"
  inner join "product_characteristics" as "pc" on "pc"."productId" = "p"."id"
  inner join "characteristics" as "c" on "c"."id" = "pc"."characteristicId"
where
  (
    (
      "c"."id" = 1
      and "pc"."value" = 'value1'
    )
    or (
      "c"."id" = 2
      and "pc"."value" = 'value2'
    )
    or (
      "c"."id" = 3
      and "pc"."value" = 'value3'
    )
  )
```